# Can I skip the downloading and patching phase that happens before the game launches?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm trying to get StarCraft 2 to run, and it installs fine. However, my internet connection is woeful. Is there a way to skip the downloading and patching phase that happens before the game is actually launched?

At the moment it just hangs forever at the  "updating" screen.

Alternatively, if the patches are available for download somewhere, I could grab them at work and that would be fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to play the game offline, you need to log on at least once. In order to log on, you need to get that first patch. So unfortunately, no I don't think you can play without it. If you want to play online (which includes the single-player campaign if you want achievements etc.) you must always be fully up-to-date with patches, similar to World of Warcraft an other online games.

The patcher itself should have links to technical support sites in case you are having difficulties. You may need to adjust your router, firewall, or peer transfer settings.

Comment: there's no problem, it's just very, very slow... (1h20m to get it all, and my connection drops every 20 minutes)

Comment: @Brice you may find this link useful: http://us.blizzard.com/support/article.xml?locale=en_US&articleId=21065&parentCategoryId&pageNumber=1&categoryId=3635

Comment: Thanks tzenes, I found that page while googling around too, but it really is my connection, rather than a firewall or router problem. (A straight forward webpage can take minutes to load. I feel like I'm back on dialup...). As far as the patch mirrors go, they don't carry the SC2 patches, only older games.